# Looping within an XElement declaration

Tags: c#, xml

I'm new to C# / .Net

I'm creating an XML document using XDocument and writing it with a nested declaration, mixing elements and attributes like so:

```
var document = new XDocument();
var form = new XElement("form");
var formheader = 
    new XElement("formheader",
        new XElement("formtitle", "My Form",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang","en")
        ),
        new XElement("formtype", "Medical"),
        new XElement("formversion", "1.0.0.0")
    );
form.Add(formheader);
document.Add(form);
document.Save("form.xml");
```

The actual thing is much bigger. Anyway, I would like to build parts of this with a loop of some sort. I know how to do that but I was hoping to do it more inline so am I able to do something along the lines of:

```
var formheader = 
    new XElement("formheader",
        new XElement("formtitle", "My Form"),
        new XElement("formtype", "Medical"),
        new XElement("formversion", "1.0.0.0"),
        foreach (item in items) 
        {
            new XElement(item.x, item.y),
        }
    );
```

...or can it not be done this way?

Many thanks!

**Update**

Might be that - having declared what *items* is - we can do it this way:

```
var formheader = 
    new XElement("formheader",
        new XElement("formtitle", "My Form"),
        new XElement("formtype", "Medical"),
        new XElement("formversion", "1.0.0.0"),
        from item in items
        select new XElement("this", item)
    );
```

...or similar.

Comment: Use LINQ: `items.Select(item => new XElement ...)` or `(from item in items select new XElement ...)`, as you prefer.

Comment: Ooo I think I know what you mean @JeroenMostert